# How to update value of a field for all page in AEM?

Tags: aem

I create a site with AEM (Adobe Experience Manager). I have a page type as property-page. The property-page have a field type "Number of event in a page". I want to modify the number of event for all property page.

How to do that?

Thank you & kind regards,

Answer (score 0):

There is no mass-update feature in AEM. Ask your developers for support. They either write you a little tool. Or they could generate a lot of curl-requests based on a query. Another option would be the AEM Groovy Console (https://github.com/OlsonDigital/aem-groovy-console). There you or your developers could write a script.

Finally you can do it one by one manually. Take a look into crx/de, which might be a little bit faster.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to bulk update the page property you may use OTB [Bulk Editor feature](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/administer/operations/bulk-editor.html). [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lCkoi4gGXg8) is a video explaining how to use this.

There is a similar [ACS tool](https://adobe-consulting-services.github.io/acs-aem-tools/features/csv-resource-type-updater/index.html) for updating sling:resourceType property. You can extend and customize this tool if not happy with OTB feature.